# Commutative Algebra: Quasi-Frobenius Implies Frobenius

Tags: commutative-algebra

> Let $A$ be a commutative Algebra. Then quasi-Frobenius implies Frobenius, i.e. if $A$ is injective as a left module, then $_AA \cong {}_ADA$.

My lecture notes only say this implication is true because $A$ is basic. It is easy to see that $A$ is basic but I do not get how that helps me here.